# Addition of new column in Spring Hibernate application database

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I'm trying to add a new column in existing table of the database(Oracle 10g), managed by a spring and hibernate application.

To add the new column in the table:

1. I manually used alter command to add new column named "LAST_EXIT_TIME" of type TIMESTAMP, nullable.
2. Added the new class member with getters and setters in the existing class, used as entity for hibernate:

> ```
> @Entity(name="EMPLOYEE")
> public class Employee implements Serializable {
>   @Id
>   @Column(name="ID", nullable = false)
>   private long id;
>
>   @Column(name = "NAME")
>   private String name;
>
>   @Column(name = "LAST_ENTRY_TIME")
>   private Date lastEntryDate;
>
>   @Column(name = "LAST_EXIT_TIME") //this is the new column
>   private Date lastExitDate;
>
>     .
>     .
>     [auto generated public getters setters]
>     .
> }
> ```

When I use the getter and setter for lastExitDate, I'm unable to fetch or set values in the/from database. Am I missing something?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).
Is there an error when you try to fetch/set values?

Comment: sorry for the missing information, I'm getting null, even if there is some value in the database when using getter, no errors or exceptions

Comment: please double-check the column name `LAST_EXIT_TIME` and type `Date` in the database

Comment: Can you post your Dao code?